# Stripe: HTML Checkout iOS Cordova wont open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, stripe-payments

I've built an app which uses stripes checkout html form element. It appears to work well on Android(cordova) and browser.

On ios cordova the popups dim effect happens for 5secs and then it goes back to normal (no popup opened) and on safari the checkout form opens on a different tab instead of being a popup.

Also the form is custom but even the basic form doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have any error  in console ?

Comment: It's actually expected behavior for the pop-up to appear in a separate tab; as mobile devices work against pop-ups rather aggressively (much more so than desktop browsers).  If you're trying to make it show up on the same page, that could be why it's not working.  Let it open in a tab and that should behave as you would expect.

Comment: Running into the same issue here, it worked in Cordova ios 3.9.2 as a popup. Seems to have been broken in 4.0.0

Comment: Are you able to open any simple popups other than stripes checkout ?

Comment: I had the same problem running a Telerik hybrid app under cordova iOS 4.0. I switched back to 3.8 and now it's working again.

Answer (score 5):

I have been having the same issue on ios.
Needed to add two lines to the config.xml

```
<access origin="*" /> <allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.com/*" />
```

http://checkcoding.com/q/32610/javascript-ios-cordova-stripe-payments-using-stripe-checkout-with-cordova-ios-4-0-0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I solved this by adding this line to the "mobile-config.js" file :

```
  App.accessRule('https://*.stripe.com/*', { type: 'navigation' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these two in `config.xml`:

```
    <allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.com/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.network/*" />
```